# Javascript Increment and Decrement operator

Tags: javascript, logic

`let i = 1; i = i++ - --i + ++i - i--; console.log(i);`

The result shows 0 how is it working with i++ as 1, --i as 1, ++i as 2 and i-- as 2.

As I understand i++ should be 1, --i should be 0, ++i should be 1 and i-- should be 1.

As post increment or decrement should alter later, pre-increment or decrement works instant.

Please clarify what am I doing wrong in it.

Comment: "*--i should be 0*" - only when `i` was `1` before. But `i++` already incremented it to `2`!

Comment: "*As post increment or decrement should alter later*" - I think the part you're missing is that "later" is not "after the whole statement" or something, but still during the evaluation of the expression, right after taking the value that would become the result.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take it step by step:

i++ returns the value 1 as you say, but it also increments the variable i.
so i now has the value 2.

--i takes 1 off i and returns the value of i, in this case therefore 1.

[So far we have i++ - --i having the value 0 therefore.]

Now ++i increments i which becomes 2 and returns that value

[So far therefore we have 0 - 2]

Finally we have i-- which returns the value of i which is 2 (and then takes 1 off it, but that isn't seen as we then update the lhs (the i variable) with -2 + 2 which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If we breakdown the expression step by step:

- i++ - This is a post-increment operation. It means the current value of i (which is 1) is used in the expression, and then i is incremented by 1. So, i++ evaluates to 1, and after this operation, i becomes 2.
- --i - This is a pre-decrement operation. It means i is decremented by 1, and then the new value (which is 1) is used in the expression. So, --i evaluates to 1.
- ++i - This is a pre-increment operation. It means i is incremented by 1, and then the new value (which is 2) is used in the expression. So, ++i evaluates to 2.
- i-- - This is a post-decrement operation. It means the current value of i (which is 2) is used in the expression, and then i is decremented by 1. So, i-- evaluates to 2, and after this operation, i becomes 1.

Now let's substitute these values into the original expression:
`1 - 1 + 2 - 2`

Now, when we perform the arithmetic operations the console.log(i) would output 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
let i = 1; i = i++ - --i + ++i - i--; console.log(i);
```

**Lets open [i = i++ - --i + ++i - i--;]:**

```
i = i=i+1 - i=i-1 + i=i+1 - i=i-1
```

**stage-1 => i++ => i=i+1**

value of i is 1 (as i++ make post-increment i.e increment value after assigning it)
stage-1 = 1

Now for stage-2 value of i has been incremented so, i = 2 now because of previous post-increment operator,

**stage-2 => --i => i=i-1**

value of i is 2, but it become 1 because of pre-decrement operator,
stage-2 = 1

**stage-3 => ++i => i=i+1**

value of i is 1,but it become 2 because of pre-increment operator,
stage-3 = 2

**stage-4 => i-- => i=i-1**

value of i is 2 but it remains 2 because of post-decrement operator not yet applied,
stage-4 = 2

**Important Point: Post Decrement Operator not yet applied.**

**Now let calculate,**

**stage-1 - stage-2 + stage-3 - stage-4**

**1 - 1 + 2 - 2 = 0**

**The value got stored in i before the last post-decrement operation. So, we got 0 in i.**

Just like if we do:

```
let i = 0; i = i--; console.log(i);
```

We get 0.